# Google maps Unirgy_StoreLocator extension for Magento

Tags: google-maps, magento

has anyone used Unirgy_StoreLocator extension for Magento? i've got the Google map showing up but how can i change the default map location and zoom value? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. need to edit

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40, -100), 4);
```

in unirgy > storelocator > map.phtml